# how to interpret HRESULT -1072868846

Tags: msdn, hresult

anyone help to interpret what is HRESULT -1072868846?  I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719669%28VS.85%29.aspx but none of the listed ones match...

the function i'm calling is 
    `hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(
            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            NULL, pType);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With err.exe from the Platform SDK:

```
# for decimal -1072868846 / hex 0xc00d5212
  MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND                                      mferror.h
# No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the
# content. %0
# 1 matches found for "-1072868846"
```

Converting it into hex with calculator in programmer mode and searching for the hex works well too.

Comment: any idea why it's causing so? the function i'm calling is                                                                              hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(
            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            NULL, pType);

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that API well :-(